# MongoDB - Get last document based on multiple fields

Tags: mongodb

I've got a special case of query that I need to perform as optimized as possible,

### Problem:

I have a collection of messages, each message has a field of groupID and I need to get last message of each groupID, but I don't want to perform one query for each of my groups, instead I wan't to give an array of groupIDs and get an array of Messages

### Solutions so far:

I managed to come up with two soloutions
1. perform query for each groupID which works fine takes about 200 ms to complete but performs many requests on MongoDB
2. use Aggregate to groups messages based on GroupID and and then select first of each group which is really slow and takes about 4000 ms

### Code

```
var filter = Builders<Message>.Filter.Eq("GroupID", groupID);
var sort = Builders<Message>.Sort.Descending("Date");
return await MessagesCollection.Find(filter).Sort(sort).Limit(1).FirstAsync();
```

what I'm looking for is a way to batch queries or do one query that can return first of mesage of given groupID, any idea??
any help will be appreciated 
thanx in advance

Comment: show your queries and structure of doc

Comment: @tarashypka I added the code